# How to make maximised window display accross the whole screen in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

I'm rendering a window containing a chart to a div, so that it appears in a certain place on my web page. When I click on the maximise button on the window, I want it maximise to take up the whole screen. Currently it just maximises to the dimensions of the div it is residing in.

I understand that if I render the window to the body, then when the window maximises it takes up the whole screen however the problem with this approach is that then I lose control over where the window is displayed on the page hence I render it to a div. If anyone knows an alternative way of positioning the window on the page, I'd be happy to try this out.

Appreciate any help,

Comment: Which extjs version do you use?

Comment: You could try to set `myWindow.constrain = false` before maximizing.

Comment: A workaround I could think of would be to create a new window, that is not constrained, on the maximize event of the original window and move the content there. When this window is closed or de-maximized move the content back to the constraint window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be suitable depending on how strict the placement of the window is and the layout of your app, but you can use `x` and `y` config properties to tell the `Ext.Window` where to render...

EDIT: You can also use `window.setPosition(x, y);` to tell the window to move to a specific position also. You could hook into the `resize` event of the window, or... just trigger it manually from the code that is maximizing/minimizing your window.

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
   title: 'Hello',
   height: 200,
   width: 400,
   layout: 'fit',
   x: 20,
   y: 20,
   items: {
      xtype: 'grid',
      border: false,
      columns: [{header: 'World'}],
      store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {})
   }
}).show();
```